# Error while setting up Stellar Python SDK on Amazon EC2

Tags: python-sdk

SO I run the command `sudo python3.6 -m pip install stellar-base` and I am getting the error:

```
e)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from requests->stellar-base)
Collecting six (from SSEClient->stellar-base)
  Using cached six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pbkdf2 (from mnemonic->stellar-base)
  Using cached pbkdf2-1.3.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: ed25519, crc16, six, SSEClient, stellar-base, pbkdf2
  Running setup.py install for ed25519 ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-wo9p69f8/ed25519/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-1b66ht7p-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ed25519
    copying src/ed25519/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ed25519
    copying src/ed25519/keys.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ed25519
    copying src/ed25519/test_ed25519.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ed25519
    copying src/ed25519/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ed25519
    UPDATING build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ed25519/_version.py
    set build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/ed25519/_version.py to '1.4'
    running build_ext
    building 'ed25519._ed25519' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/ed25519-glue
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/ed25519-supercop-ref
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Isrc/ed25519-supercop-ref -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c src/ed25519-glue/ed25519module.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/src/ed25519-glue/ed25519module.o
    src/ed25519-glue/ed25519module.c:17:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've installed the Python dev package.

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev
```